# Swift Update Struct in View

Tags: swift, swiftui

I apologize I am new to Swift and may be going about this completely wrong.

I am attempting to call the mutating function on my struct in my view to add additional phones or emails. This is my Struct.

```
struct CreateCustomer: Codable {
        var Phone: [CustomerPhone]
        var Emails: [String]
        init() {
            Phone = [CustomerPhone()]
            Emails = []
        }
        public mutating func addPhone(){
            Phone.append(CustomerPhone())
        }
        public mutating func addEmail(){
            Emails.append("")
        }
    }
struct CustomerPhone: Codable {
    var Phone: String
    var PhoneType: Int
    init(){
        Phone = ""
        PhoneType = 0
    }
}
```

I am attempting to add a phone to my state var with the following

```
Button("Add Phone"){
    $Customer_Create.addPhone()
}
```

I get the following Error

> Cannot call value of non-function type 'Binding<() -> ()>' Dynamic key
> path member lookup cannot refer to instance method 'addPhone()'

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Customer_Create` is a state property variable (like below) then you don't need binding, use property directly

```
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var Customer_Create = CreateCustomer()

  var body: some View {
     Button("Add Phone"){
       Customer_Create.addPhone()    // << here !!
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be accessing the `Binding` via `$`, you should simply access the property itself.

```
Button("Add Phone"){
    Customer_Create.addPhone()
}
```

Unrelated to your question, but you should be conforming to the Swift naming convention, which is lowerCamelCase for variables and properties - so `customerCreate`, not `Customer_Create`.